# Image e and preimage of a set using logical connectors

Tags: propositional-calculus

This might appear silly, I know that

$$
\begin{array}{l}
f(A) = \left\{f(x) : x \in A \right\} \\
f^{-1}(A) = \left\{x : f(x) \in A \right\}
\end{array}
$$

If $y\in f(A)$ is fixed can this be expressed by the condition

$$
\exists x, x\in A \Rightarrow f(x)=y
$$

Can we do a similar thing with the pre-image?

Basically I'd like to express those definition using logical connectors. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

$y\in f(A)$ is equivalent to
$$ \exists x\,(x\in A\land f(x)=y)$$
and $x\in f^{-1}(A)$ is equivalent to 
$$ f(x)\in A.$$

Answer (score 1):

$y\in f(A)$ is equivalent with: $\exists x\;[x\in A\wedge f(x)=y]$.

So $\wedge$ instead of $\implies$.

---

We have the (very useful) equivalence:$$x\in f^{-1}(A)\iff f(x)\in A$$

So if $x\in f^{-1}(A)$ is fixed then this can be expressed by the condition $f(x)\in A$.

Does this meet your needs?